# R - Convert a column to single factor level

Tags: r, data-structures

I have the following problem. I have done tests, in this test have a set of samples ("`Sample`"), different categories ("`Individual_class`") for which I wrote down a score ("`Score_individual_class`"), and I also gave a final score("`Final_Score_Sample`") for each sample. This is an example:

```
df<-data.frame(Sample = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
               Individual_class = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
               Score_individual_class = c(10,20,50,80, 30,60),
               Final_Score_Sample = c(80,80,90,90,120,120)

)
  Sample       Individual_class   Score_individual_class  Final_Score_Sample
      1                A                     10                 80
      1                B                     20                 80
      2                A                     50                 90
      2                B                     80                 90
      3                A                     30                120
      3                B                     60                120
```

Now I would like the `Final_Score_Sample` to be in between the `Score_individual_class` with `Individual_class` = C. Like this:

```
  Sample       Individual_class    Score_individual_class
      1                A                     10
      1                B                     20
      1                C                     80
      2                A                     50
      2                B                     80
      2                C                     90
      3                A                     30
      3                B                     60
      3                C                    120
```

I've tried this:

```
df_test<-df[,c("Sample", "Final_Score_Sample")]
df_test<- df_test[!duplicated(df_test), ]
df_test$Individual_class<-"C"
df_test$Individual_class<-as.factor(df_test$Individual_class)
names(df_test)[names(df_test)=="Final_Score_Sample"] <- "Score_individual_class"
df_final<-left_join(df, df_test)
```

But this didn't work. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here implemented in base R:

```
# Your data
df<-data.frame(Sample = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
               Individual_class = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
               Score_individual_class = c(10,20,50,80, 30,60),
               Final_Score_Sample = c(80,80,90,90,120,120))

# Data with correct format
df1 <- df[,1:3]

# Data with incorrect format
df2 <- unique(df[,c(1,4)])
df2$Individual_class <- "C"
colnames(df2)[2] <- "Score_individual_class"

# Gathering data again
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

# Sorting 
df <- df[order(df$Sample, df$Individual_class),]

# Result
  Sample Individual_class Score_individual_class
1      1                A                     10
2      1                B                     20
7      1                C                     80
3      2                A                     50
4      2                B                     80
8      2                C                     90
5      3                A                     30
6      3                B                     60
9      3                C                    120
```

Comment: Thanks! I would recommend @Roma's solution with tidyverse, as it is the most clean. I just did this one, as it is often nice to be able to do this kind of things in base R :)

Comment: Yes, very true, I started with your solution and then did the answer from @Roma :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace last line of your code with a following one:

```
df <- rbind(df[c(1:3)],df_test)
```

And then sort df:

```
df <- df[order(df$Sample,df$Individual_class),]
```

Comment: @Lotw is referencing several `df_test` in their code. Which one are you referring to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ...https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Just replace the last line in the original code with those two above.

Comment: So basically a duplicate of my answer?

Comment: @EsbenEickhardt's answer is also essentially the same. Not to say mine is anything special, I'd happily delete it, it just seems a bit silly to have three so similar answers to the same question.

Comment: I did not mean to "steal" your solution. I just prefer explicit explanations myself, and I saw there was done - so I decided to make a quick one. I agree, our solutions are pretty close.

Answer (score 1):

#### Result

```
  Sample Individual_class Score_individual_class
1      1                A                     10
2      1                B                     20
3      1                C                     80
4      2                A                     50
5      2                B                     80
6      2                C                     90
7      3                A                     30
8      3                B                     60
9      3                C                    120
```

#### Code

```
df %>%
    select(1:3) %>%
    bind_rows(df %>% 
                  select(1, 4) %>%
                  group_by(Sample) %>%
                  summarize(Score_individual_class = first(Final_Score_Sample)) %>%
                  mutate(Individual_class = "C")) %>%
    arrange(Sample)
```

#### Data

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(Sample = c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                 Individual_class = c("A","B","A","B","A","B"),
                 Score_individual_class = c(10,20,50,80, 30,60),
                 Final_Score_Sample = c(80,80,90,90,120,120),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     library(tidyverse)

     df <- bind_rows(df %>% 
            dplyr::select(Sample,Individual_class,Score_individual_class),
           df %>% 
           dplyr::select(Sample,Final_Score_Sample) %>% 
            mutate(Individual_class = "C") %>% 
            rename(Score_individual_class = Final_Score_Sample)) %>% 
           arrange(Sample)
```